# Monitored stream class

Tags: python, stream

I am trying to create a stream object that triggers a callback function any time data is written to it.

```
class MonitoredStream():
    def __init__(self, outstream, callback):
        self.outstream = outstream
        self.callback = callback

    def write(self, s):
        self.callback(s)
        self.outstream.write(s)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.outstream, attr)
```

This works fine when I call the write method directly, but I would love to have it work also when I have a subprocess' output hooked to the stream.  For example:

```
def f(s):
    print("Write")

p = sub.Popen(["sh", "test.sh"], stdout=MonitoredStream(sys.stdout, f))
p.communicate()
```

This just sends output directly to sys.stdout, bypassing the write function completely.  Is there a way that I can monitor this output also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that `subprocess.Popen` doesn't use the Python interface to the pipe - it instead gets the file descriptor and then uses that to write to the pipe directly, which, as you give the attributes of the `stdout` pipe, means it uses that, bypassing your code.

My best guess at solving this is to make a new in-between pipe that sits in the middle to let you deal with the stream yourself. I would implement this as a context manager:

```
import sys
import os
from subprocess import Popen
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def monitor(stream, callback):
    read, write = os.pipe()
    yield write
    os.close(write)
    with os.fdopen(read) as f:
        for line in f:
            callback(line)
            stream.write(line)

def f(s):
    print("Write")

with monitor(sys.stdout, f) as stream:
    p = Popen(["ls"], stdout=stream)
    p.communicate()
```

Although you could, of course, still use a class:

```
import sys
import os
from subprocess import Popen

class MonitoredStream():
    def __init__(self, stream, callback):
        self.stream = stream
        self.callback = callback
        self._read, self._write = os.pipe()

    def fileno(self):
        return self._write

    def process(self):
        os.close(self._write)
        with os.fdopen(self._read) as f:
            for line in f:
                self.callback(line)
                self.stream.write(line)

def f(s):
    print("Write")

stream = MonitoredStream(sys.stdout, f)
p = Popen(["ls"], stdout=stream)
p.communicate()
print(stream.process())
```

Although I feel this is less elegant.

Comment: These are nice ideas, but if I understand them correctly, they both wait until the stream is closed before applying the callback function to the entire output.  I would ideally like to apply the callback function any time there is a line available to read in the stream.

Comment: That is true, although, as far as I understand, `subprocess.communicate()` already does that, so it should be a non-issue.

Comment: Oh I see.  If that's the case I will have to find another approach.  My use case is that I have a long-running process that produces log output, and I would like to be able to monitor the output and react in something like real time (before the process has completed).  I will just set the output to `subprocess.PIPE` and read from it line-by-line rather than using `subprocess.communicate()`